# Java 8: iterating across some Map elements

Tags: loops, java-8, hashmap

I'm having a `validate` method that return a `boolean`.

I'm invoking this method (Java 7) as follow:

```
    boolean isValid = true;
    for (String key: aMap.keySet()) {
        isValid &= validate(key, aMap.get(key));
        if(!isValid) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I would like to rewrite this code in Java 8.

Java 8 allows iterating across a Map using:

```
aMap.forEach((k,v) -> validate(k, v));
```

But this won't work:

```
aMap.forEach((k,v) -> isValid &= validate(k, v));
```

**Question**

How can I rewrite the the Java 7 code into Java 8 to achieve the same result?

**Note**

Raised a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426673/java-8-iterating-across-all-elements-of-a-map) (but this time, for the iteration to continue through all the `Map` elements)

Comment: Use Stream.allMatch()

Comment: If you short-circuit, there is no sense in using the `&=` operator. Further, you should not perform a lookup for every key you’re iterating over. So, the Java 7 code would look like `boolean isValid = true; for(Map.Entry<String,ValueType> e: aMap.entrySet()) if(!validate(e.getKey(), e.getValue()) { isValid = false; break; }`. It would be even simpler when being encapsulated in a method: `for(Map.Entry<String,ValueType> e: aMap.entrySet()) { if(!validate(e.getKey(), e.getValue()) return false; } return true;`.

Comment: @Holger that's perfectly true for the first question. I realized it and edited the question to add a second one without exiting. Sorry for the confusion. The reason of the second question is: in some part of the code, the iteration must continue no matter the result of isValid, in order to build a report. It must still return true or false if at least one validation has failed. Up voted your comment. I will raise the second question is another post or it will add confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean isValid = aMap.keySet()
                .stream()
                .allMatch(key -> validate(key, paramRow.getRowMap().get(colName))
```

As a side note, what does `paramRow.getRowMap().get(colName)` do? And where do you get `colName`? May be you don't have to recompute this for every single key