# Java 8: iterating across all elements of a Map

Tags: java-8, hashmap

I'm having a `validate` method that return a `boolean`.

I'm using invoking this method (Java 7) as follow:

```
    boolean isValid = true;
    for (String key: aMap.keySet()) {
        isValid &= validate(key, aMap.get(key));
    }
```

I would like to rewrite this code in Java 8.

Java 8 allows iterating across a Map using:

```
aMap.forEach((k,v) -> validate(k, v));
```

But this won't work:

```
aMap.forEach((k,v) -> isValid &= validate(k, v));
```

**Question**

How can I rewrite the the Java 7 code into Java 8 to achieve the same result?

Note:

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425632/java-8-iterating-across-a-map) . The difference in this post is that I want to iterate this time across all the items of the `Map` (for the `validate` method to build a validation report). `isValid` must return `true` if no validation error occurred, or `false` if at least one occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
boolean isValid = aMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> validate(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .reduce(true, Boolean::logicalAnd);
```

as, unlike `anyMatch`, `allMatch`, etc, Reduction knows no short-circuiting. However, your requirement of executing all `validate` method calls suggests that there are side-effects within that method. It’s important to understand that these side effects must be non-interfering, i.e. it should not matter in which order these method calls are made and even concurrent evaluation of multiple elements should not break it.

Even when these requirements are met, it is rather discouraged to have such side-effects in a functional operation. E.g., the next developer looking at your code may say, “hey that looks like we should use `allMatch` here”…

So I’d stay with the loop. But when processing the associations of a `Map`, you should not loop over the `entrySet()`, to perform a lookup for every key, but rather use

```
boolean isValid = true;
for(Map.Entry<String, ValueType> e: aMap.entrySet())
    isValid &= validate(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Starting with Java 10, you may use

```
boolean isValid = true;
for(var e: aMap.entrySet()) isValid &= validate(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

eliminating the most annoying syntactical element of that loop.

Comment: You say: " it should not matter in which order these method calls are made and even concurrent evaluation of multiple elements should not break it." But the stream you wrote won't be run in parallel as with `parallelStream()`. Can you please explain what you mean ?

Comment: Well, it’s about the contract. The sequential stream will call the method in the same order the source map’s iterator delivers them, but that’s not a guaranteed property. It’s even worse, if the source map hasn’t a defined encounter order in the first place, like with `HashMap`. We could predict the sequential invocation order in same cases, but it would still be wrong code if we rely on the order. As a rule of thump, code using the Stream API should be written in a manner that turning it to parallel does not break it, even if we don’t use it (yet).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `aMap.forEach((k,v) -> isValid &= validate(k, v));` is that the variable captured in a lambda expression should be `final` or `effectively final`. This is the same for `anonymous inner classes`in Java.

So, to answer your query, you can convert `isValid` to a `final` one element array, like this:

`final boolean[] isValid = {true};` and then 
`aMap.forEach((k,v) -> isValid[0] &= validate(k, v));`

You can also probably make it `atomic`, but that would require more code changes. This solution is much simpler.

Comment: It definitely work. Its an original solution, despite at the cost of the array. Still, up voted thanks.